# which loop is faster?

Tags: java

I have this loop

```
for (it= someCollection.iterator; it.hasNext(); )
{
    //some code here
}
```

I changed it to:

```
for (it= someCollection.iterator;; )
{
    if (!it.hasNext())
        break;
    //some code here
}
```

The second code ran a little bit faster in unit tests in junit on eclipse.
Is the second loop faster? I'm asking because the times given by Junit are not too exact, but they give an approximate value

Comment: Just for fun, also try `for (Object item : someCollection) { /* Some code here */ }`

Comment: I think you will struggle to determine this as it may be dependent on JVM, machine etc etc

Comment: What caused you want to find out "which was faster"?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @mlk as I said times given by running Junit tests

Comment: I guess the second one must be slower, you've got a NOT operator more.  In all cases, the difference is really, really minimum, and won't impact.

Comment: So what caused you to change the loop? Has the business has said it is too slow? If not then use 'for(X item : items) {...}' as it is easy to read.

Comment: @mlk I'm trying to optimize the code, though I know that "Premature optimization is the root of evil"

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize the code? What metric have you use to determine that the code is "unoptimized"? As this NOT  a "unit test" should be the starting point for your optimizations.
The chance that change the loop structure will have any noticeable affect on the overall run time is tiny. As such looking at the loop structure is a waste of your time. You would be MUCH better off looking at the logic or the number items you are looping over, or you access to external resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking into this sort of problems, it's useful to think about the generated bytecode in terms of block control flow graph, where a block is a sequence of bytecode instructions that can only be entered from its first instruction and only left after its last instruction (leaving out exits to simplify the problem).

Using this example code:

```
    for (Iterator it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    System.out.println("Out");
```

You would get the following block control flow graph. I've put back the equivalent bytecode into source for readability, but all the instructions generated by `System.out.println(it.next());` belong to one block, since you can't jump in the middle or get out of it.

[image: Loop Control Flow Diagram]

If you check a [compiler book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886), you'll find that `it.hasNext()` dominates `System.out.println(it.next())` because you need to go through `it.hasNext()` to go to `System.out.println(it.next())`. The edge from `System.out.println(it.next())` to `it.hasNext()` is called a *back-edge* because it links a node to one of its dominators. This is what formally defines what the loop is. The first statement in the `for`-loop (`Iterator it = c.iterator()`) doesn't actually belong to the loop. There is no difference with a while loop preceded by this statement, except for the scope of the declared variable, but this doesn't matter once compiled.
The first block (`it.hasNext()`) is the loop header.

A second example like this would produce the same graph:

```
    for (Iterator it = c.iterator();; ) {
        if (!it.hasNext()) {
           break;
        }
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    System.out.println("Out");
```

The main difference is that there may be some useless `goto` statements depending on the compiler strategy.

If you look at the generated bytecode using `javap -c` for these two examples, you get this (this was compiled with `javac`, you may get something slightly different if you compile with the Eclipse compiler, for example):

```
public void loop1();
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class java/util/ArrayList
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   12:  astore_2
   13:  aload_2
   14:  invokeinterface #5,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   19:  ifeq    37
   22:  getstatic   #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   25:  aload_2
   26:  invokeinterface #7,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   31:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   34:  goto    13
   37:  getstatic   #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   40:  ldc #9; //String Out
   42:  invokevirtual   #10; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   45:  return

public void loop2();
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class java/util/ArrayList
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/util/ArrayList.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
   12:  astore_2
   13:  aload_2
   14:  invokeinterface #5,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
   19:  ifne    25
   22:  goto    40
   25:  getstatic   #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   28:  aload_2
   29:  invokeinterface #7,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   34:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   37:  goto    13
   40:  getstatic   #6; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   43:  ldc #9; //String Out
   45:  invokevirtual   #10; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   48:  return
```

The only difference is that the first one uses `ifeq 37` to go straight to the end or proceed with the next block (22), whereas the other one uses `ifne` to go to the block after `goto` (25, equivalent to 22 in the other) and uses a `goto` to go to the end otherwise. This is effectively equivalent and a modern JIT compiler should optimise this little difference without trouble. Apart from this, your two loops are exactly the same.

I'm not sure how you've made your measurements, but you should also be aware that it's not because `System.nanoTime()` give you a result in nanoseconds that it has a resolution of that order, far from that. High-resolution timers are quite hard to implement and will depend on the hardware and OS. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29):

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily
>   nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no
>   guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as
>   that of currentTimeMillis().

It's likely that, if you don't get a high enough difference, you won't get something significant compared to the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect them to compile to identical bytecode.

Comment: Hmmm, so there is no point in trying to optimize this loop, I guess

Answer (score 0):

They should exeCute in the exact same time.

What is with?

```
while(it.hasNext())
```

Comment: well, there is no difference between the different java loops AFAIK, the compiler should take care of that

Answer (score 0):

the two examples are exactly the same.
Note: since there is no update statement in the loops i.e something like `it.next()` both loops will probably run forever, unless they only have no elements.
Or that you put them here like this for illustration only.

Comment: Can you explain how you came to this solution?

Comment: As explained in previous comments..
a loop is composed of 4 steps
1-initialization: which is executed only once, before the loop starts
2-check condition
3-run code
4-update

here initialization is `it= someCollection.iterator`
condition check is `it.hasNext()`
and no update
the difference is that the coder moved the condition check from before the loop body to the start of the loop body, which compiles to the same code.

Answer (score 0):

loop syntax

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

1. The initialization step is executed first, and only once. This step allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon appears.
2. Next, the Boolean expression is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement past the for loop.
3. After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the update statement. This statement allows you to update any loop control variables. This statement can be left blank, as long as a semicolon appears after the Boolean expression.
4. The Boolean expression is now evaluated again. If it is true, the loop executes and the process repeats itself (body of loop, then update step,then Boolean expression). After the Boolean expression is false, the for loop terminates.

In your 2nd code 4th step is not executed when if condition is true. so that it's faster than 1st code.

Comment: There is no "update" expression in the examples in the question.

Comment: @Bruno i know about that, i am talking about for loop syntax.

Comment: Your steps 3 and 4 won't be executed in either examples: it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @Bruno logically there are 3 expression in loop, in question 3rd expression is empty means. when code executed compiler will go and try to check 3rd expression. that's it.

Comment: From a control-flow graph point of view, the node with `it.hasNext()` is both the loop header and the only exit node, in the two examples. Whether or not there's an update statement has nothing to do with it. You can read [section 4.3 of this dissertation](http://www.harbulot.com/phd-thesis.pdf) if you want some background on loops and control flows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9057/discussion-between-riddhish-chaudhari-and-bruno)